# What does this error message "Received discontinuity error" mean? From Apple's mediastreamvalidator

Tags: http-live-streaming

Using Apple's mediastreamvalidator to validate the m3u8 file, I got an error message: "Received discontinuity error", but I didn't find any explanation for this error message in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2235/_index.html

Does anybody know what this error mean, and whether this error will cause any issues?

My mediastreamvalidator's version is: Beta Version 1.1(150608)

Below is the mediastreamvalidator's result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_1444446455_hls_64944_116-10.m3u8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Playlist Syntax:    OK

Processed 15 out of 15 segments:

test_1444446455_hls_64944_116-10_00003.ts:

    ERROR: (-12976) Received discontinuity error
    --> Track ID: 258


test_1444446455_hls_64944_116-10_00007.ts:

    ERROR: (-12976) Received discontinuity error
    --> Track ID: 258


test_1444446455_hls_64944_116-10_00010.ts:

    ERROR: (-12976) Received discontinuity error
    --> Track ID: 258


test_1444446455_hls_64944_116-10_00014.ts:

    ERROR: (-12976) Received discontinuity error
    --> Track ID: 258


Average segment duration: 2.00 seconds
Playlist target bitrate: Average:  3.24 Mbits/sec, Max:  3.72 Mbits/sec
Segment bitrate: Average:  3.04 Mbits/sec, Max:  3.65 Mbits/sec
Average segment structural overhead: 76.21 kbits/sec (2.50 %)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A discontinuity can be caused by:

- changes in encoding such as: different file format, number, type and identifiers of tracks, different encoding parameters
- non-consistent timestamp sequences such as gaps or roll-overs

Such cases must/should be indicated with an [EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-16#page-11) tag.

Check if your encoder is producing valid output.